# Can't boot into TWRP recovery after flashing custom ROM?

Tags: recovery-mode, custom-roms, twrp

I flashed the latest pixel experience Android Q build for Redmi note 7 pro using the TWRP recovery after unlocking the bootloader. The ROM seems to be working fine and the phone boots into it without any issues however when I try to boot into the TWRP recovery, it doesn't boot into it and instead I get a Redmi logo on the screen that doesn't go away. What should I do to boot my phone into recovery? I haven't rooted my device yet, just unlocked the bootloader.

Could it have something to do with the fact that I forgot to flash the TWRP image from the TWRP recovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the custom ROM package will include the boot image too. And on A/B partition devices, the recovery rests is in the boot image. So, if the custom ROM has written your boot image, then your TWRP should be gone. What will load will depend on the recovery included in the boot image. It could be stock, something else or nothing.